# Quarkus application hangs after live reloading

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application (v2.1.3) and I run it in dev mode using:

```
mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

However every time I make any change, I get this in the logs:

```
2021-08-24 21:44:01,395 WARN  [io.qua.dep.dev.JavaCompilationProvider] (pool-1-thread-1) Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'com.austinv11.servicer.ServicerProcessor' less than -source '11', line -1 in [unknown source]
2021-08-24 21:44:01,434 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor] (pool-1-thread-1) Restarting quarkus due to changes in ImageUtil.class.
2021-08-24 21:44:01,459 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) Metrics scheduler closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,460 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-08-24 21:44:01,462 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) Metrics reporters closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,464 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) App info kafka.consumer for kafka-consumer-stats-in unregistered
2021-08-24 21:44:01,466 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.int.ConsumerCoordinator] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-websocket-in, groupId=generic] Revoke previously assigned partitions websocket-0
2021-08-24 21:44:01,471 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.int.AbstractCoordinator] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-websocket-in, groupId=generic] Member kafka-consumer-websocket-in-b7af8600-b31b-4ce6-b48c-147053aa0862 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:49284 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,477 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) Metrics scheduler closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,477 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-08-24 21:44:01,479 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) Metrics reporters closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,482 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) App info kafka.consumer for kafka-consumer-websocket-in unregistered
2021-08-24 21:44:01,485 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.pro.KafkaProducer] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-1) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-websocket-out] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 10000 ms.
2021-08-24 21:44:01,490 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-1) Metrics scheduler closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,491 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-1) Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-08-24 21:44:01,492 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-1) Metrics reporters closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,493 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-1) App info kafka.producer for kafka-producer-websocket-out unregistered
2021-08-24 21:44:01,495 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.pro.KafkaProducer] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) [Producer clientId=kafka-producer-stats-out] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 10000 ms.
2021-08-24 21:44:01,497 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) Metrics scheduler closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,501 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-08-24 21:44:01,504 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.met.Metrics] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) Metrics reporters closed
2021-08-24 21:44:01,506 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.uti.AppInfoParser] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) App info kafka.producer for kafka-producer-stats-out unregistered
```

followed by this exception:

```
2021-08-24 21:45:02,602 WARN  [io.ver.cor.imp.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 61079 ms, time limit is 60000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:917)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1240)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:267)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:396)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:389)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$3.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:109)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$3.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:97)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:160)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$2189/0x00000008010f4c40.handle(Unknown Source)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:96)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:158)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$2187/0x00000008010f5040.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

and the application stops responding to any HTTP request, I have to restart it.

It was actually working a while back, and I think a Quarkus upgrade broke this feature for me.

Comment: The log looks fine, that's what one would expect from a shutting down application. Is that all there is in the log? Nothing more is printed, the app is just stuck? If so, I think I'd recommend filing a bug.

Comment: Yes, please create an issue in our tracker with a reproducer. Thanks.

Comment: Anecdotally, I do find myself having to add "clean" to my maven CLI more often in Quarkus 2.x than 1.x. So, I typically run `mvn clean compile quarkus:dev`

Comment: Benjamin, if you created the GitHub issue, could you please link here?